# VLOOKUP for a range of letters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I need to take a range of letters for example:

- if the cell contains A, B, C, or D and fill a cell with P1.
- If the cell contains E, F, G, or H fill a cell with P2.
- If the cell contains I, J, K,or L fill a cell with P3.

Can I do this with a VLOOKUP?  I cannot get it to work so far.

Comment: Better share some sample data with us,, & the expected output, help us to fix the issue. ☺

Comment: What is actually in the cells, a single letter or a string containing one of those letters?  Can it contain more than one of those letters?  What goes into the target cell, the literal string `P1`, `P2`, or `P3`, or the contents of cell P1, P2, or P3?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a VLOOKUP, using this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$12,2,0)
```

Please note that you will need to create a reference table on a second worksheet (named Sheet2 in the formula) as follows:

```
      --------
     | A | B  |
 -------------
| 1  | A | P1 |
 -------------
| 2  | B | P1 |
 -------------
| 3  | C | P1 |
 -------------
| 4  | D | P2 |
 -------------
| 5  | E | P2 |
 -------------
| 6  | F | P2 |
 -------------
| 7  | G | P2 |
 -------------
| 8  | H | P2 |
 -------------
| 9  | I | P3 |
 -------------
| 10 | J | P3 |
 -------------
| 11 | K | P3 |
 -------------
| 12 | L | P3 |
 -------------
```

---

This can also be done without a reference table using INDEX, MATCH and a little math.

```
=INDEX({"P1","P2","P3"},ROUNDUP(MATCH(A1,{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"},0)/4,0))
```

This formula assumes that your P numbers increment every four letters, and can easily be extended to encompass the whole alphabet.